# How do you copy ships and multitools back to your main save from Omega Expedition?

Tags: no-mans-sky

In the new Omega Expedition, I've read many articles saying you can copy the Starborn Runner and Atlas Scepter multi-tool from your expedition back to your main save... but no clear explanation of how this is done. The ones I got are very nice and I would like to retain them in my main save.

Do I do it before I end the expedition? Or after? Does it include all technologies and cargo?

(Note: this is distinct from claiming the Starborn Runner and Atlas Scepter from the Quicksilver vendor)

Comment: You know... part of me was hoping someone asked this question, part feared it already knowing how lengthy writing the answer would be...

Answer (score 2):

It is quite poorly explained, I'll give you that.

### PRE-REQUISITE

You ***MUST*** have started the expedition at the new expedition terminal at the Space Anomaly (on the left near the quicksilver/expedition reward vendor). You can't copy any item if you started the expedition on a new save slot from the main menu.

### Copying Multitools and Ships from the expedition to the main save

**At any time** you can copy you currently equipped multitool and active spaceship from your expedition branch to your "main" save. To do so:

- (start in expedition mode)
- select the multitool / ship you want to copy.
- return to the primary save. To do that either go to the expedition terminal and select the "Return to primary save" button or open the game options and select the same button from there. **The second procedure should be preferred since after you complete all the expedition milestones the terminal can also be used to TERMINATE the expedition in which case you can't return to this mode afterward if you need to transfer more stuff.**
- back to your primary mode, go to the Expedition Terminal at the Anomaly
- here you can copy the multitool and the ship you left active in the expedition. ***BE CAREFUL: apparently the copy can overwrite your current multitool/ship if you don't have a free slot, so check that you have less than 12 ships and 6 multitools before copying!***
- you can now use the same terminal to go back to the expedition mode to complete whatever objective you have left.
- NOTE: copying a ship only copies the installed tech. Cargo slots will NOT be copied

### Copying Items and Tech from the expedition to the main save

**When you are ready to complete the expedition** you can copy up to 8 tech and 24 cargo items from your expedition to the main save. To do so:

- (start in expedition mode)
- go to the Expedition Terminal at the Anomaly
- this time select the "End Expedition" button
- as soon as you press the end button you will get a pop-up warning that informs you that you are about to finalize the expedition. Note that you may not get this one if you already saw the "everything completed" popup that you get when you complete all the main ***AND*** optional milestones (this behavior may have been changed by a patch, so there are sightly different reports)
- ***NOTE: this is the point of no return: if you proceed you won't be able to return to the expedition, so please be sure you copied your ships / multitools if you needed them before continuing.
- you should be back at the terminal. Notice how the right panel is now unlocked. The interface will only show a single button "End Expedition". **At this point the terminal won't give you the option to "Return to your primary save" any longer.**
- fill the slots with the items you want to take back.
- NOTE: you can't bring back the 4 memory orb because Hello Games is stupid. You are also unable to bring back creature eggs so only the Atlas knows **WHY** the five optional milestones all had eggs rewards that you won't be able to take back with you (my bet is the same as before: Hello Games is VERY stupid)
- when you are done, press the End Expedition button.
- you will get some screen that will award you credits / nanite based on the left over items in your expedition mode. Note that the conversion isn't that great, so some suggest to scrap your ships in the expedition before ending it (you get more money and some upgrades that you can transfer to the main mode)
- Congrats! You are back to the main mode and you won't be able to return to the expedition. The terminal will show you a congratulation message until the next expedition stars.

And now the moment you all waited for...

### Caveats:

The copy process comes with a series of exploit that can be used to go beyond what you were probably supposed to bring back from the expedition. **Please be careful and always read carefully to avoid causing any damage to your save.**

**--Copy infinite ships and multitool--**
You probably though that you could copy only one ship and multitool from your expedition to you main save, but that is not true. In reality the game only performs two checks:

- the item you are trying to copy should not already exist in the save. This means that you can't copy  the same multitool twice **as long as you still own the previous copy**
- you won't be able to copy the expedition Atlas multitool / Starborn Runner ship **after** you claimed the same rewards from the Quicksilver vendor (but you can do the opposite!!)

Given that you can copy all the ships/tools you want by following the following simple procedure:

- select the item as active in the expedition mode
- return to primary mode using the option in the game menu
- copy the item
- return to the first step to copy another item

That said, unless you found a really cool ship or multitool there aren't many reason to copy multiple items since you can simply get the Atlas staff and the Starborn Runner from the vendor instead.

What you can do instead is **copying the Starborn Runner multiple times**. Why would you do that? The answer is simple.

The Starborn Runner comes with a tech called "Photonix Core". This is an item that was previously exclusive to the pre-order ship at game launch and can't be found in any other way. For these reason many player wanted to try to obtain as many spare cores as possible. This can be achieved by following these simple steps:

- (select the Starborn Runner as your active ship in the expedition mode)
- back in the primary mode, copy the Starborn Runner
- take the core and store it somewhere
- ***scrap the Starborn Runner you just copied***
- copy the Starborn Runner again
- repeat until your patience last

Notice that to avoid any issue it is safer to do this ***BEFORE*** claiming the vendor Starborn Runner (doing so locks you from copying the Starborn Runner you got in the expedition!). Also please take notice that you... are actually paying those cores since **copying the Runner will cost quite a bit nanites** and even if you sell everything after scraping you won't cover all the costs.

**--Exploit: Copy infinite tech / cargo items--**
After you choose to end the expedition and unlocked the item transfer panel the expedition terminal interface no longer shows the "Return to primary save" button but you can still access the same option in the game options menu.
If you fill the item transfer panel in the terminal, exit the terminal and then return to the main mode from the option menu you will find that you are able to pick up the item and then return to the expedition to transfer more.

***I advise not doing this*** since some players reported some issues after trying. For example, some players reported that the tech slots were empty when they checked them in the main save but they were also gone in the expedition.

### And a last thing...

You may be tempted to copy your Atlas staff to the main save just to have two of them (if you really want to, remember to copy the staff before claiming the one from the Quicksilver vendor since doing so will lock you from copying it) but there is no reason to do so.

***The placement of the supercharged slots on the staff you can get from the vendor is NOT fixed and changes every time you open the window, therefore you are able to reroll the placement by simply closing the prompt without accepting the trade and opening it again***

You may think this isn't "that" relevant....
Well, let me tell you something. A staff with an l shaped placement for the three available supercharged slots  (the staff comes at A quality) can easily get to 22k damage potential just with the pre-installed upgrades...

### Final notes

When you end the expedition, all the bases and discoveries will get "copied" to your main save. Probably you won't care... so I suggest you delete the bases **before** terminating the expedition.

I hope you found this useful, fellow Traveler. Oh, and please... when returning from the expedition please remember to transfer back you personal effects: you don't want anyone to thing you are just one of those lame *hitchhikers* without a ship that never remember where they left their towel.

16 / 16 / 16 - Transmission Complete.

Comment: Thank you! This confirms what I'd pieced together. Now I can finish the expedition without feeling like I'd missed out on something.

Comment: 16/16/16 - kzzt - that was long but - kzzt - work, transmission received.